# How does one analytically solve for the contours of an arbitrary bivariate density?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function

This [slide deck](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/lectures/MultivariateNormalDistribution-I.pdf) shows how to solve for the contours of a multivariate normal, using an eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix. This seems to rely on the convenient ellipsoid shape of the normal's contours, and its relation to the $\chi^2$ distribution.

I'm curious how to approach this problem when the shape of the contour is less convenient. For example, the picture below shows two independent beta distributions, two independent gammas, and the combination of each.

Given an expression $f(\textbf{x})$ for the density of a bivariate $\textbf x$ and $0 \lt p \lt 1$, we derive a contour by finding the region $D$ such that

$$\iint_D f(\textbf{x}) d \textbf{x} = p$$

and that for $\textbf{x} \in D$ and $\textbf{y} \notin D$, $f(\textbf{x}) \ge f(\textbf{y})$. Per @whuber, "the boundary of the closure of $D$ will be a level curve ('contour') of $f$." (H/T!) I'd think that one would (1) express the level curve of the density for a given $c$ (2) use this expression, and $f$, to find $c$ such that the integral over the region bounded by the curve is equal to $p$.

In the beta-beta case, the level curve would seem to be given by
$$x_1^{\alpha_1-1}(1 - x_1)^{\beta_1-1}x_2^{\alpha_2-1}(1 - x_2)^{\beta_2-1} = c$$

But, it isn't immediately clear to me how to translate this condition into a double integral.

Is there some means to easing this calculation, perhaps reparameterizing the densities by their distance from the mode, or some other change of variables? Alternatively, is there some other principled, better-aimed means of approaching this problem?

[image]

Comment: Although this question's thrust is apparent, in the details it's murky.  When $C$ is a boundary, "$\int_C$" represents a *line integral.* I believe what you are looking for is the following. Given $0 \lt p \lt 1$, you wish to find a *region* $D$ such that (1) $\iint_D f(\mathbf x)d\mathbf x=p$ and (2) whenever $\mathbf x\in D$ and $\mathbf y\notin D$, $f(\mathbf x)\ge f(\mathbf y)$. For continuous $f$, the boundary of the closure of $D$ will be a level curve ("contour") of $f$, so you seem to be asking a standard Calculus question: given $f$, find its level curves.